# cant sudo apt-install

Tags: kernel, package-management, thirdpartyapps, package

whenever i try to install i get this error:

```
E: The package linux-headers-4.1.0-040100rc2-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

or

```
E: The package linux-headers-4.1.0-040100rc2-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Unable to apply corrections for half-installed packages
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed a third party kernel and then removed the source this could happen

It's not ElementaryOS's problem (because EOS didn't had that kernel version - Release Candidate) but I may help you

You can remove the package even if it's broken with the command:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <package>
```

---

And lastly, it's `sudo apt install` not `sudo apt-install`

Comment: thank you. I think that worked. first time i installed linux and i just followed some "first steps with eos" posts.. lesson learned

Comment: feel free to ask about those "first steps tutorials" before taking one, gl